# How to create Reusable vertica sql by reading medata

Tags: sql, metadata

We have a fixed length flat file which is stored in a table as a single column (say table name: `flatfile1`). We have another table (Metadata) where the file format is stored with start and end positions of each fields.

Now we want to write a select sql to separate the fields from table `flatfile1` by reading the positions from table Metadata.

We have 50+ such flat files where we are trying to figure out a reusable approach to write the sql. Each of these files will have different number of fields with different length.

How could we go about this?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.